# Rails - Exclude an attribute from being saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a column named updated_at in postgres. I'm trying to have the db set the time by default. But Rails still executes the query updated_at=NULL. But postgres will only set the timestamp by default when updated_at is not in the query at all.

How do I have Rails exclude a column?

Comment: By Rails convention, a field named "updated_at" or "created_at" on your table will be set by Rails at save time during update and create actions. Perhaps what you're trying to do within the DB is conflicting with this conventional behavior. You might try giving your auto-update field a different name.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable this behaviour by setting ActiveRecord::Base class variable
record_timestamps to false.

In config/environment.rb, Rails::Initializer.run block :

```
config.active_record.record_timestamps = false
```

(if this doesn't work, try instead ActiveRecord::Base.record_timestamps = false at the end of the file)

If you want to set only for a given model :

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.record_timestamps = false
end
```

Credit to Jean-FranÃ§ois at http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/72569

Comment: While this will probably work - you have to keep in mind that it will also destroy the normal functioning of created_at - which might not be desired. Also - it will destroy this functioning for *every* model... not just the model in the question.

Comment: It can be applied to individual models as well, see the second code snippet.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. @Jean-FranÃ§ois, I've tried your suggestion in the model but viewing my logs still show that updated_at is still inside the query.

Answer (score 0):

I've been running into a similar issue in Rails 2.2.2.  As of this version there is an attr_readonly method in ActiveRecord but create doesn't respect it, only update. I don't know if this has been changed in the latest version.  I overrode the create method to force is to respect this setting.

```
def create
    if self.id.nil? && connection.prefetch_primary_key?(self.class.table_name)
      self.id = connection.next_sequence_value(self.class.sequence_name)
    end

    quoted_attributes = attributes_with_quotes(true, false)

    statement = if quoted_attributes.empty?
      connection.empty_insert_statement(self.class.table_name)
    else
      "INSERT INTO #{self.class.quoted_table_name} " +
      "(#{quoted_attributes.keys.join(', ')}) " +
      "VALUES(#{quoted_attributes.values.join(', ')})"
    end

    self.id = connection.insert(statement, "#{self.class.name} Create",
      self.class.primary_key, self.id, self.class.sequence_name)

    @new_record = false
    id
end
```

The change is just to pass false as the second parameter to attributes_with_quotes, and use quoted_attributes.keys for the column names when building the SQL.  This has worked for me.  The downside is that by overriding this you will lose before_create and after_create callbacks, and I haven't had time to dig into it enough to figure out why.  If anyone cares to expand/improve on this solution or offer a better solution, I'm all ears.